# Content isn't hidden on url-rewrite url, but is on normal url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, file-extension

I am using this code to prevent a `<div>` element from being displayed on the page example.php:

```
<?php if($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] !== '/example.php') { ?>
<div>Example</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Using this code in `.htaccess`, I can change the page name from `example.php` to `example`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

When I visit http://website.com/example.php, the `<div>` element does not show - but when I visit http://website.com/example, it does - how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `strpos()`:-

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], 'example') === false) { ?>
   <div>Example</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @TheCodesee  glad to help you. :):)